# How to center text in Android title bar containing a button?

Tags: android, layout

I have a ListView which contains a LinearLayout on the top of the View which functions as a Title Bar. The List can scroll, but the title bar stays put. In the title bar I want a "Back" button but that causes the title text to become un-centered:

[image: uncentered text]
I added a second button of the same size (on the right hand side of the title bar) and made it invisible so as to act as a "spacer" for the text to center on but then I loose a lot of title bar real-estate:

[image]

Is there a way to tell Android to center the title text and disregard the Back button? Perhaps this is just the way life is but thought I'd run it by everyone before proceeding with a kludgy second, invisible button or something.
Thanks

Comment: is 3rd button is not disply ?

Comment: have you tried the `FrameLayout`.. back frame with text view and front frame with back button..

Comment: nirav -- yes, I forgot to make the right-most button visible in the screen shot. I updated the first screenshot to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use relative layout instead of linearlayout,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffaa" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:text="Header Title Embiggeden"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a LinearLayout, you can use a RelativeLayout for your header. And using layout paramenters so that :

- Back button is align with the left edge of it's parent.
- TextView take the whole parent (LayoutParam.FILLPARENT) with gravity CENTER

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS FOR YOU. I DID THIS IN MY PROJECT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Back" >
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30sp" ></TextView>
       </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10sp" >
        </ListView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is what you needed and change the color of second RelativeLayout according to your need.

Comment: I hope this is perfect solution for your problem. i have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Then try to use Relative Layout,
The text is in

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and the two buttons in

```
1.android:layout_toLeftOf="text id" 
2.android:layout_toRightOf="text id"
```

Answer (score 1):

take `relativelayout` instead of `linearlayout`.set text view property `centerinvertical=true` 
and set button `alignParent=left.`

Answer (score 1):

Set padding-left of TextView equals invisible Button Width

Answer (score 1):

You can use Relative Layout instead of LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" android:maxLines="1" 
        android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or you can use FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```